# Mac Excel 2011 - Excel Web Query - Loops and Selections

Tags: excel, macos, vba, excel-2011

I am using Excel 2011 to execute the following query:

```
WEB
1
http://careers.accel.com/careers_home.php?p=1

Selection=EntirePage
Formatting=All
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
```

I was wondering if there is a way to loop through the values of pages, i.e. "p=1" in the URL auto increments to "p=2". Additionally this query returns the pages numbers on top of the table, I was wondering if there is a way to modify my selection so only the main table appears.

[image: Excel Rendering Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Solved using visual basic. Couldn't figure out removing the page numbers though:

```
' Macro2 Macro
'
For x = 1 To 5
Worksheets("names").Select
Worksheets("names").Activate
mystr = "URL;http://careers.accel.com/careers_home.php?p=1"
mystr = Cells(x, 1)
Worksheets("pages").Activate
'Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x
'


 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A" & Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1))
        .PostText = "accel"
        .Name = False
        .FieldNames = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = 1
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .SaveData = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .UseListObject = False


    End With
    Next x
End Sub
```